# No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version,Why i am getting this error?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to test my app on an iPhone 4, however I'm getting this error:

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Comment: what iOS Version and Xcode Version did you use? Which iOS Version is on your iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Xcode creates applications for ARM7 by default.

To support the iPhone 3G and other arm6 devices, you need to specify arm6 and arm7 in in the Architectures list, and set the device requirements to only arm6 in the plist.

Comment: This answer i found in this website,but the solutions is not that,itried.i think another solution might be there

Comment: selected old version of iOS in xcode deployment still it didnt work

Comment: wht deployment target u hv set n wht is on device.

Comment: i thnk ur deploymrnt trgt is 5.1 n device has 5.0

Comment: my device is 5.1 and my deployment target is 5.0

Comment: @the saad: i cn hrdly nderstnd wht u wrt. cn u plz wrt whle wrdz? thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error message if your Xcode is too old, ie you haven't updated it but you have updated your phone.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed my app from iPhone to Universal, Xcode automatically changed the **Deployment Target** from 4.3 to 6.1, my device had 6.0 so it wasn't recognized.

Changing the value back to 4.3 solved the problem.